# Mockito thenCallRealMethod method calls other mocked class as real

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a class with two methods and i want to test one of them but it uses the other method. Therefore, i have to use Mock annotation to mock all methods and use thenCallRealMethod to test my method. I applied this approach and it worked. But, i faced an another problem. The problem is caused by my testing method which wrapped by thenCallRealMethod. It didn't use Mocked classes and invoked real classes. So, it caused null pointer error. Thanks for any comments.

**Test**

```
...

@Mock
ClassA a;

@Mock
ClassB b;

@Test
public void testing() {

Mockito.when(ClassB.methodX()).thenReturn(x);
Mockito.when(ClassA.methodZ()).thenReturn(Mockito.Any());
Mockito.when(ClassA.methodY()).thenCallRealMethod();
ClassA.methodY();

}

...
```

**ClassA**

```
...
@Autowired
ClassB b;
public byte[] methodZ(){
...
}
public void methodY(){
b.methodX();
methodZ();
}
...
```

Comment: `ClassA` instance is a mock, so no dependencies are injected hence a `NullPointerException`. You should create in instance of `ClassA` and inject the dependencies and next create a Spy instead of a mock to do what you want to achieve. Also the code you posted with the mocking doesn't make sense, `methodZ` is `void` so returning something won't work.

Comment: Actually methodZ returns something in my problem so i missed this relevance between real problem and this example. I will edit my question. Also i will try your answer. Thank you for your answer.